# How to make my date format in a concatenation as follows Mmm-YY SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, text, format

Would like to make my date format in a concatenation as follows Mmm-YY

Here is my current code

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Contract]
      ,[Expiry Date]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Strike Price]
      ,[Contract Type]
      ,[Spot Price]
      ,[Price]
      ,[Rate]
      ,[Origin]
      ,CONCAT(Convert([Expiry Date] + 'Mmm-YY') ,'_',contract,'_',[Strike Price],'_',[Contract Type],'_',Quantity)
```

I would like it to read as follows

Dec-21_DCAR_22546_P_20
Sep-21_DCAR_22546_P_20

With my current code it is reading like so

2021-09-16_DCAR_22546_P_20
2021-12-15_DCAR_22546_P_20

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will help us help you. I notice in the above, however, you have a `CONVERT` function with only one parameter. `CONVERT` accepts 2 or 3 parameters, the first being the date type to convert *to*, the 2nd the value to convert, and (optional) 3rd is the style code. Also `[Expiry Date] + 'Mmm-YY'` won't work if `[Expiry Date] ` is strongly typed date (and time) data type, which I hope it is. `'Mmm-YY'` isn't a valida te and time value, so would value to be converted and/or you won't be able to use a plus (`+`) operator with the date and time data type.

Comment: Instead of your `CONCAT(CONVERT(...` you might want to try the following in order to get the month and year part of your desired result: `SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,@d,100),3), '-', CAST(YEAR(@d)%1000 AS CHAR(2)))` (@d is my date variable)

Comment: Hey @Larnu this was code that produced what I getting currently

`
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Contract]
      ,[Expiry Date]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Strike Price]
      ,[Contract Type]
      ,[Spot Price]
      ,[Price]
      ,[Rate]
      ,[Origin]
   ,CONCAT([Expiry Date],'_',contract,'_',[Strike Price],'_',[Contract Type],'_',Quantity)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find an answer

```
SELECT [Date]
      ,[Time]
      ,[Contract]
      ,[Expiry Date]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[Strike Price]
      ,[Contract Type]
      ,[Spot Price]
      ,[Price]
      ,[Rate]
      ,[Origin]
      ,CONCAT(Left(DATENAME(Month,[Expiry Date] ),3),'-',Format([Expiry Date],'yy','en-US'),'_',contract,'_',[Strike Price],'_',[Contract Type],'_',Quantity) as 'Tag'
```

Date    Time    Contract    Expiry Date Quantity    Strike Price    Contract Type   Spot Price  Price   Rate    Origin  Tag
2021-04-01  17:00:00.0000000    NPNQ    2021-06-17  9   3343.5  P   3744.72 7918.44 34.75   offscreen   Jun-21_NPNQ_3343.5_P_9

Thank you for your assistance. Perhaps there is a better way of writing this